# Is it possible to import Authentication data to Firebase Emulators?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I periodically update my emulator’s Firestore data to be as close to production as possible.

I recently updated Custom Claims logic with the Auth emulator turned on. None of my users can be accessed from the Admin Auth SDK by uid (as they aren’t in emulators).

Updating claims as per the docs:

```js
getAuth()
  .setCustomUserClaims(uid, { admin: true })
  .then(() => {
    // The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
    // next time a new one is issued.
  });
```

I (foolishly) solved this by turning off Auth Emulator which modified Custom Claims for production users while developing and testing.

Is there a way to export Auth Data and import into Emulators, as there is for Firestore?

Or alternatively,

Is there a way to specify uid (to match Firestore) when creating fake users in Auth Emulators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify uid (to match Firestore) when creating fake users in Auth Emulators?

You can specify the user ID when using [`createUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) with Admin SDK. If you have a script that migrates Firestore documents from production to emulator, you can create users in the same using the document IDs.

Alternatively, you can [`firebase auth:export`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#auth-export) command to export users from production inn case you just need to read the data from a local file.

If you are just referring to emulator data then you can import dumped data back in emulators by:

```
firebase emulators:start --import dump_file
```

Comment: Given a changing list of Firestore user docs, will this skip users who have already been created, or will I need to keep track of the Users who have already been created in the emulators?

Comment: @RafaelZasas you'll have to keep the track, other wise it'll throw an error that user with UID already exists. Maybe you could use `Promise.allSettled()` so even if SDK throws error other promises will still continue

Comment: @RafaelZasas just to confirm, you case is transferring users from prod to emulator right and not restoring users from last emulator session (that is supported using dump file) the `--export-on-exit` flag?

Comment: periodically I do run with the export on exit flag, however I update my local emulators-data/ more often.

Answer (score 6):

Simplified answer to the problem of exporting prod authentication data into emulator authentication.  First run

```
firebase auth:export FILENAME --format json
```

Now, you have a json with your prod users.  Next, run your emulator with the command:

```
firebase emulators:start --import EMULATOR_DATA_FOLDER_NAME --export-on-exit
```

Close the emulators.  Now, inside your emulator data folder, you should see folders for each of the emulators you are running.  Go to the auth_exports folder to see your accounts.json.  Simply replace the users array inside that folder with the exported users you got from the initial command.  When you run a new emulator instance, just be sure to start it with the same start command as above if you want changes to be included.

Comment: FFS!!!!!! I was on search for this answer so long! The steps you mentioned is so crutial and I don't see anyone else talking about this.

Thank you!!!!